# beginSheetModalForWindow - the alert window disappear

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What's wrong with this piece of code implemented in the AppDelegate ? The alert appears very shortly over the window and then disappears. The alertDidEnd callback method is never called.

I've tried to clean the product in Xcode 4.6.1 and to rebuild it, without success.

```
- (void) alertDidEnd:(NSAlert *)alert returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [[alert window] orderOut:self];
    alertResult = returnCode;
    NSLog(@"alertDidEnd called");
}

- (void) showAlert
{
    NSAlert *saveAlert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];

    [saveAlert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
    [saveAlert setMessageText:messageText];
    [saveAlert setInformativeText:informativeText];
    [saveAlert addButtonWithTitle:defaultButtonTitle];
    [saveAlert addButtonWithTitle:secondButtonTitle];

    [saveAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window]
                        modalDelegate:self
                        didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                        contextInfo:nil];
}
```

I answer myself. The problem was elsewhere in the applicationShouldTerminate method.

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply )applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *) sender
{   if(conditionOK)
        doSomeStuff;
    else    // all changes are not saved
    {   [self showAlert];
        handleButtonClicked;
    }

    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

In the else branch of the if statement showAlert is executed but "return NSTerminateNow" also. The application doesn't wait until a button is clicked in the alert. It returns immediately. So I test a response that have not yet been posted.

I will modify the applicationShouldTerminate method.

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply )applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *) sender
{   if(conditionOK)
        doSomeStuff;
        return NSTerminateNow;
    else
    {   [self showAlert];
        return NSTerminateCancel;
    }
}
```

The alertDidEnd callback method will test the returned button, do the job and send a terminate signal if necessary.

At the moment, I have not fixed the problem but I know where is the problem.

Just a question : beginSheetModalForWindow is always asynchronous or is it asynchronous only in the context of applicationShouldTerminate ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version of applicationShouldTerminate

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply )applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *) sender
{
    if([_buttonSave isEnabled])
    {   if(quitMenuTerminate)
            [self majFile];
        else
        {   [self showAlert];
            return NSTerminateLater;
        }
    }

    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

In the callback method, alertDidEnd, of beginSheetModalForWindow, I call

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES];
```

And all is OK now.